# Can docker images be used as a bootable images

Tags: docker

Is a docker image bootable by any boot-lader ( say grub ?) without using docker at all? Save the image out to a disk and bring it up as a standalone OS partition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly with a docker image, since the image is only the filesystem for the application, and not the kernel and other utilities needed to run a Linux OS (e.g. networking).

However, there is [LinuxKit](https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit), which is a container based operating system. This is how Docker runs the VMs for desktop environments (Windows and Mac). LinuxKit packages a kernel with containerd and a very simple init process, along with any images you want to start. There are a few bare metal options, but mainly it's designed to be a VM image.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Docker images don’t have their own Linux kernel, any sort of hardware device driver, any sort of console login mechanism, network configuration tools, or a wide variety of other things you need for a fully functional OS.